# MapBox Building Footprints Calculate Area on Click events - 2D

Tags: maps, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

I'm trying to create a Building footprints map for my Website.
I have styled it successfully but for some reason I can't seem to get the data under 'Tileset'.
If anyone can help, I'm willing to pay as well.

Thanks

Here's the preview link:

https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/usamamughal95/cl45gdj9l000o14pnqdv4gjes.html?title=copy&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoidXNhbWFtdWdoYWw5NSIsImEiOiJjbDQ1YXJmNjQwZjV2M2RuaXhzdm1pYjJ2In0.g-M02P6auU6mcxzUMAwVaA&zoomwheel=true&fresh=true#17.2/33.761552/-118.407553

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. A style specifies how something looks. Adding click events to access the data within a clicked feature is something you would do within an app using the map SDK code, not a style.

Answer (score 0):

The click event includes an array of all features under the mouse (from top-most down). Here is an example of how to access their properties when clicking: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/polygon-popup-on-click/

If you want to get the details of any displayed feature on the map, you can use the `queryRenderedFeatures` function. This example uses the `mousemove` event, but you can simply change that to a `click` event: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/queryrenderedfeatures/

Here is a similar example: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/queryrenderedfeatures-around-point/